# ZkSoftwareEu SDK integration

Tags: zkteco

I'm trying to integrate the ZkSoftwareEu into my app. I got the SDK and I'm already browsing its methods referencing ZKEUEmKeeperNet.dll, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to exploit the methods!

This is how i'm calling the SDK library in my code:

```
using ZkSoftwareEU;
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //working example
        Console.WriteLine("AAAAAAA: " + ZkSoftwareEU.CZKEUEMNetClass.S_AdminCount);
    }
}
```

Has anyone worked with this or has an idea on how to get started with the use of this SDK?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have worked with ZKTeco, I need to know what kind of device do you have first.